# Generic Data Access layer to update navigational properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

I have the following Generic data access class, responsible for Database operations.

```
internal sealed class DataStore<T> : IDataStore<T>
    where T : BaseModel, new()
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public DataStore(DataContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public async Task InsertNew(T obj)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        });
    }

    public async Task<T> SelectObj(int id, Expression<Func<T, object>> includeExpression = null)
    {
        if (includeExpression != null)
            return
                await _context.Set<T>()
                    .Include<T, object>(includeExpression)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ID.Equals(id));

        return await _context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.ID.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> SelectAll(Expression<Func<T, object>> includeExpression = null)
    {
        if (includeExpression != null)
            return await _context.Set<T>().Include<T, object>(includeExpression).ToListAsync();

        return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task Update(T obj)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
             var original = await SelectObj(obj.ID);
             _context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(obj);
             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
         });
    }

    public async Task Delete(T obj)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Remove(obj);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        });
    }

    public async Task Delete(int id, Expression<Func<T, object>> includeExpression = null)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var obj = await SelectObj(id, includeExpression);
            await Delete(obj);
        });
    }
}
```

The problem with the `Update` function is, it only updates the `T` object passed through, not the navigational properties on that object.

I have tried the following, but I am stuck and not sure how I need to continue here.

```
private void GetNavProperties(T obj)
    {
        var objType = obj.GetType();
        foreach (var prop in objType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass)
            {
                var values = prop.GetValue(obj);
                //How do I go further here, setting the Entity on the context
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i know I'm not answering your question but to throw a spanner in the works... what would Update do... if it was just 'await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` provided the T obj was originally pulled from the context in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around, I ended up with the following solution that worked for my application.

Below is the solution, with comments for explaining what it does.

```
private async Task UpdateNavProperties(T original, T newObject)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            //get type of object
            var objType = original.GetType();

            //loop through properties on the Type
            foreach (var prop in objType.GetProperties())
            {
                //Check that property is a class/reference type, and not part of the System namespace
                //string would be part of the system namespace, but my custom class not
                if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass && !prop.PropertyType.Namespace.Equals("System"))
                {
                    //get the old value
                    var oldValue = prop.GetValue(original);
                    //get new value
                    var newValue = newObject.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(newObject);
                    //update the value 
                    _context.Entry(oldValue).CurrentValues.SetValues(newValue);
                    //save changes
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And to use it, I did the following:

```
public async Task Update(T obj, Expression<Func<T, object>> includeExpression = null)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var original = await SelectObj(obj.ID, includeExpression);
            _context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(obj);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            await UpdateNavProperties(original, obj);
        });
    }
```

Comment: As this is a generic method, it will always update navigation properties even if not indented. 1) Consider the case if you need to update only Parent.

Also you can also remove multiple savechanges() it will break the transaction and may effect partial save in db if something wrong happens.

Comment: I will modify the solution for the sake of this post being read by other users, but for my example I always need it to update the Navigation properties. I do agree on the SaveChanges(), forgot about that.  Thanks for you comments